# Is there any way to get calories consumed data from Google Fit on Android and Health on iOS using Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, healthkit, google-fit

I'm using the Health package for Flutter and can get steps data from both devices but there doesn't appear to be a way to get calories consumed.

Is there any way to get the calories consumed data from iOS & Android devices using Flutter?

Comment: Health package for Flutter gives calories data as well .

Comment: Thanks @RahulKushwaha, I've managed to get the calories consumed data from iOS using the DIETARY_ENERGY_CONSUMED health data type. I haven't been able to find an Android equivalent though. What data type should I use to get calories consumed on Android?

Answer (score 0):

For these use-cases you provided. I highly recommend to use Google's new API, Health Connect.

https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/connect/client/records/package-summary#classes